# Websphere + Tomcat : CertificateException

Tags: java, tomcat, websphere

I have 2 applications deployed on 2 different servers where my GUI 
 application is on Tomcat and CAS(central authentication) on Websphere. I have created keystore file and updated the same in `server.xml` in tomcat conf.

Please find the entries below.

Tomcat:

```
<Environment name="config/centralCasServerLoginURL" 
type="java.lang.String" value="https://localhost:9443/my-sso-web/login?
method=POST"/>
Tomcat: <Environment name="config/applicationServiceURL" 
type="java.lang.String" value="https://localhost:8443/bank-client-
web/j_spring_cas_security_check"/>*
```

and

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" 
keystoreFile="C:\tmp\newKeystore1" 
         keystorePass="password" maxThreads="200" port="8443"
         protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https" 
secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS"/>*
```

I am able to run both the application individually but when I configured CASAuthentication profile in that time I am able to login CAS but after it redirected to my GUI application URL (i.e. https://localhost:8443/bank-client-web/j_spring_cas_security_check) it is throwing below error.

Could you please help me with that?

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/bank-
client-web] threw exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching localhost found
    at org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(CommonUtils.java:295)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.retrieveResponseFromServer(AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:33)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.validate(AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:178)
    at org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider.authenticateNow(CasAuthenticationProvider.java:131)
    at org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(CasAuthenticationProvider.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.doAuthentication(ProviderManager.java:130)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching localhost found
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)     
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching localhost found
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(HostnameChecker.java:221)
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:95)
    ... 55 more
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simply your client-side library peforming strict hostname verification, comparing "localhost" in the URL to the hosts WebSphere's certificate is valid for.

Simplest fix is to address this server by it's actual hostname rather than localhost.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. can you please elaborate it more.

Comment: I am executing below URL first. it will then redirect to second url listed below.Here, browser first ask for CAS credentials and then after credential will redirect to GUI application and here it is failing. My websphere server where CAS is installed is also on local machine.. hence I am using localhost. 
1) https://localhost:8443/bank-client-web/
2) https://localhost:9443/dcisc-sso-web/login?method=POST&service=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8443%2Fbank-client-web%2Fj_spring_cas_security_check%3Bjsessionid%3D04318CA2CBDCACE83383342B5855DB78